# For loops and divisibility of numbers

Tags: java, loops

I've been learning java for about a week now and have been messing around with `for` loops for the last few days. I have used `if` statements to test the divisibility of a number on several properties. below is what I've got so far.

```
int g = 18;

if ((g % 2 )== 0 && (g % 3)== 0)
{
    System.out.println("g is divisible by 2 and 3");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("g is not divisible by 2 and 3");
}

if ((g % 7 )== 0 || (g % 9) == 0)
{
    System.out.println("g is divisible by 7 or 9");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("g is not divisible by 7 or 9");
}

if (((g % 2 )== 0) && ((g % 3) == 0) && ((g % 5) != 0))
{
    System.out.println("g is divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("g is not divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
}
```

I am trying to use a `for` loop to amend each of the programs above to test all of the numbers between 1 and 100 in a single run of each program. Below is my `for` statement.

```
for(g=1;g<=100;++g)
```

Trouble is, my program doesn't even run. Have I got it completely wrong? A point in the right direction will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you remember the main-method?

Comment: SORRY. Main method is public static void main (String[] args)
  {

Comment: Can we see the ENTIRE code? if there's a problem it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: @user3065332: Please accept the answer which provided you the most useful solution for your question. Thank you and enjoy programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int g = 1; g <= 100; g++) {
            if ((g % 2) == 0 && (g % 3) == 0) {
                System.out.println(g + " is divisible by 2 and 3");
            } else {
                System.out.println(g + " is not divisible by 2 and 3");
            }

            if ((g % 7) == 0 || (g % 9) == 0) {
                System.out.println(g + " is divisible by 7 or 9");
            } else {
                System.out.println(g + " is not divisible by 7 or 9");
            }

            if (((g % 2) == 0) && ((g % 3) == 0)) {
                if ((g % 5) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(g + " is divisible by 2 and 3 and 5");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(g + " is divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
                }
            } else if ((g % 5) == 0) {
                System.out.println(g + " is not divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
            } else {
                System.out.println(g + " is not divisible by 2 and 3 and 5");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just 1 little query is discovered, on number 51, and a few others, it says "g is not divisible by 2 and 3 but 5". but the fact is 51 is not divisible by 5 either. how can i amend the print message without ruining everything?

Comment: Edited the reply, please check. We need to modify the last part of the code. Let me know if you have any problem understanding the logic

Comment: Aah, i see it now. you broke the statement that checks the divisibility by 5 into a statement of its own. This certainly make its easier to test all the numbers from 1 to 100 correctly. You sir, are a genius. I understand the logic. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should run:

```
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for( int g = 1; g < 101; g++){
             if ((g % 2 )== 0 && (g % 3)== 0)
                System.out.println("g is divisible by 2 and 3");
             else
                System.out.println("g is not divisible by 2 and 3");    
             if ((g % 7 )== 0 || (g % 9) == 0)
                System.out.println("g is divisible by 7 or 9");
             else
                System.out.println("g is not divisible by 7 or 9");    
             if (((g % 2 )== 0) && ((g % 3) == 0) && ((g % 5) != 0))
                System.out.println("g is divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
             else
                System.out.println("g is not divisible by 2 and 3 but 5");
        }
    }
}
```